# SQL: SELECT same attribute in the table from different references

Tags: sql

I'm new in SQL language and RDBMS. I'm trying to show the same column from the same table but using different references.

### Problem

I have the following database and tables:

```
DATABASE: PRODUCTS  
    PROD (CodProd <PK>, Descr, PrecoUnit, QtdeEst)


    PROD_SIM (CodProd <PK>, CodProdSim <PK>)
    PROD_SIM (CodProd) REFERENCES PROD (CodProd)
    PROD_SIM (CodProdSim) REFERENCES PROD (CodProd)
```

I was asked to show all the products `desc` that have other products considered similar to them, and show the `desc` column from the similar product too.

### Example

I have the following data:

```
PROD:
    (0, `spachetti`, 12.5, 2)
    (1, `noodle`, 8.0, 4)

PROD_SIM:
    (0, 1)
```

I want to show this:

```
+-----------+-------------+
|  Product  | SimilarProd |
+-----------+-------------+
| spaghetti | noodle      |
+-----------+-------------+
```

### Tried

```
SELECT PROD.Desc, PROD.Desc FROM PROD
INNER JOIN PROD_SIM ON PROD_SIM.CodProd = PROD.CodProd
```

But of course, this will not work, because I'm selecting the same table twice and I don't know how to specify from what reference should the selected column consider display `Desc`.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Sorry but it's a simple exercise, just for training purposes. Not have a real implementation.

Comment: A simple example would make it much easier for all of us to understand!

Comment: See if it's more understandable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your request and your schema correctly (I don't have enough reputation to comment), I think you're only one join away from achieving the desired result:

```
SELECT A.Desc original_product, B.Desc similar_product
FROM PROD A 
INNER JOIN PROD_SIM S ON A.CodProd = S.CodProd
INNER JOIN PROD B ON S.CodProdSim = B.CodProd
```

Comment: See if I get this correctly: You do a join using the same table `Prod` just for select from another reference `S.CodProdSim = B.CodProd`?  And, `A` in`FROM PROD A` is an alias to `PROD` that you use after `A.CodProd = S.CodProd`?

Comment: Exactly. By using an alias for each instance of the PROD table I'm able to use it twice as two distinct result sets (A and B). This allows me to reference one result set with S.CodProd and an another result set with S.CodProdSim.

Comment: Have an explicit way to create an alias? That has the same behavior as your implementation.

Comment: What do you mean an explicit way? This is an alias that's valid for that query only and can be used in a number of places. Read more here (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) for an introduction.

Comment: I said that only because of the `as` keyword. I was thinking that the use of aliases has to explicitly use `as` in the queries. Thanks a lot for the help!